# Multiple assertions in with pytest.raises

Tags: python, pytest

I'm trying to test code where I want to test multiple rules within a single with pytest.raises(ValueError) exception, is there a Pythonic way to do this? In the example below, I want to test that all 4 function calls will throw the value error.

```
With pytest.raises(ValueError):
  function_that_throws_exception(param1)
  function_that_throws_exception(param2)
  function_that_throws_exception(param3)
  function_that_throws_exception(param4)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest to use `parametrize`:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("param", [param1, param2...])
def test_function_that_throws_exception(param):
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
       function_that_throws_exception(param)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
params_that_should_throw = [param1, param2, param3, param4]

for param in params_that_should_throw:
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
       function_that_throws_exception(param)
```